# Two markers keep looking at one another in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have implemented google map with two marker and draw a polyline between them. Now I want to show marker icon in that below way. I tried it calculating the slope of the line. But because of positive and negative slop, I am unable to fix it. 
Any approach or calculating to solve this.

[I would like to implement the two marker icon in that way ( the draw one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlpeX.jpg)

My Code

```
 public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.
            fromResource(R.mipmap.map_icon);

    double x1,x2,y1,y2;

    x1 = 70.2048;
    y1 = 60.2529;
    x2 = 80.0902;
    y2 =  138.7129;

    LatLng dhaka = new LatLng(x1, y1);
    LatLng chittagong = new LatLng(x2, y2);

    double slopeOfThePolyLine = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1);
    double angle = Math.atan(slopeOfThePolyLine);
    double angleInDegree = angle * 57.2958;





    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dhaka).title("First Marker").
            anchor(.5f, .5f).
         //   rotation((float) angle1).
            flat(true).icon(icon));


    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(chittagong).
            title("Second Marker").
          // rotation((float) (90 + angleInDegree)).
            anchor(.5f, .5f).flat(true).icon(icon));

    Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(dhaka, chittagong)
            .width(5)

            .color(Color.RED));


    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(dhaka));


}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference needs to be 180 degrees?

"First Marker"

```
rotation(float angleInDegree)
```

and 
"Second Marker"

```
rotation(float (angleInDegree + 180))
```

Comment: I tried it. But when I changed the coordinate of any of the two it changed. Changing the coordinates it changes the marker position. I mean first marker may be the second and second marker becomes the first. so applying your angle wont do anything much....